# See what GCP services are enabled for a project (node js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcloud

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/list), with the `gcloud` cli if you run `gcloud services list --available` you can get a list of the services that are enabled or available to be enabled for a google cloud project. What is the equivalent library/call to use to do this in node? I've taken a look at the libs [listed here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node) and can't seem to find how to do this.

I'm using [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) which is running in a node js env to go and programmatically crawl an account but it will error out if certain services are not enabled for a project when you try and run it. Basically, before I run `terraformer` I want to get a list of what services are enabled and only import those services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is curious:

```
import { google } from 'googleapis'

const usage = google.serviceusage('v1')

const project = "myProject"

const authorize = async (scopes) => {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({ scopes })
  return await auth.getClient()
}

const {
  data: { services }
} = await usage.services.list({
  parent: `projects/${project}`,
  filter: 'state:ENABLED',
  auth: await authorize(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud documentation is quite good and I would recommend a quick Google search in most cases. You can find several examples of what you are looking for [here](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/list-services).

The actual http request looks something like the following (this example does not show how to attach authentication information)

```
curl 'https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/357084163378/services?filter=state:ENABLED'
```

I would recommend submitting an Ajax request to this endpoint. If you are using Google SDKs already you should be able to get an access token to attach to the api request

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I just so happened to find that exact link myself right after I posed 